# Attempting to use multiple conditionals in one for loop, yet only two are executing

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement

I was wondering if someone would be able to assist me in what I could be doing wrong.

The idea of this program is to take 10 user inputted values representing a yearly salary and output the total taxes that are owed within the tax bracket of said salary. All salaries less than $20,000 a year pay 10% in taxes, salaries between $20,000 and $50,000 pay 20% in taxes, between $50,000 and $100,000 pays 30% in tax, and above $100,000 pays 40% in tax. However, when I input test salaries for each hypothetical tax bracket, only the ones describing salaries below $20,000 and between $20,000 and $50,000 will execute properly. The rest seem to default to the 20% tax bracket even if I were to type in a salary of say $100,000

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  int salaryBase [] = {20000, 50000, 100000};
  float taxBase [] = {0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40};
  int annualSalaries [11];
  float taxesToPay [11];

  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    printf("Enter annual salary\n");
    scanf("%d", &annualSalaries[i]);

  }
  for (int n=0;n<10;n++)
  {
    if(annualSalaries[n]<=salaryBase[0])
    {
    taxesToPay[n]=annualSalaries[n]*taxBase[0];
    }
    else if(salaryBase[0]<annualSalaries[n]<=salaryBase[1])
    {
    taxesToPay[n]=annualSalaries[n]*taxBase[1];
    }
    else if(salaryBase[1]<annualSalaries[n]<=salaryBase[2])
    {
    taxesToPay[n]=annualSalaries[n]*taxBase[2];
    }
    else if(annualSalaries[n]>salaryBase[2])
    {
    taxesToPay[n]=annualSalaries[n]*taxBase[3];
    }
  }
  printf("SALARY  TAXES\n");

  for (int g=0;g<10;g++)
  {
  printf("$%d  $%.2f\n", annualSalaries[g], taxesToPay[g]);
  }

  return 0;
  
  

}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is since there don't seem to be any mistakes (that I can see anyway, I could be wrong). Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: C does not support chaining conditionals.  C does not follow classic arithmetic conventions.

Comment: `salaryBase[0]<annualSalaries[n]<=salaryBase[1]` --> `(salaryBase[0]<annualSalaries[n]) && (annualSalaries[n]<=salaryBase[1])` or in this case with the prior tests: `annualSalaries[n]<=salaryBase[1]`.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (for us humans, the compiler does not care)  Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  Note: smaller indent widths ( for instance 2 spaces) will be 'lost' when working with variable width fonts

Answer (score 2):

As commented, you cannot say `a < x <= b` as a condition. You need to
split them as `a < x && x <= b`.
BTW you can construct a loop of the comparison
instead of repeating the tedious codes to compare. Would you please try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10            // you should not embed the "magic number" in the code

int main(void) {
    int salaryBase [] = {20000, 50000, 100000};
    float taxBase [] = {0.10f, 0.20f, 0.30f, 0.40f};
    int annualSalaries[N];
    float taxesToPay[N];
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Enter annual salary (No.%d)\n", i + 1);
        fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
        sscanf(buf, "%d", &annualSalaries[i]);  // should not use scanf()
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        taxesToPay[i] = annualSalaries[i] * taxBase[sizeof taxBase / sizeof taxBase[0] - 1];    // assign to the default value
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof salaryBase / sizeof salaryBase[0]; j++) {
            if (annualSalaries[i] <= salaryBase[j]) {
                taxesToPay[i] = annualSalaries[i] * taxBase[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("SALARY  TAXES\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("$%d  $%.2f\n", annualSalaries[i], taxesToPay[i]);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `float taxBase[] = {0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.40};`  this converting `double` values into `float` values.  Not a good idea,  Suggest:  `float taxBase[] = {0.10f, 0.20f, 0.30f, 0.40f};`  notice the trailing `f` on the values, which makes them `float` values

Comment: regarding: `for (j = 0; j < sizeof salaryBase; j++) {`  depending on the size of an `int`,  this will loop 12 or 24 times.  Suggest:  `for (j = 0; j < sizeof salaryBase/ sizeof salaryBase[0]; j++) {`  which will loop 3 times

Comment: regarding: `taxesToPay[i] = annualSalaries[i] * taxBase[sizeof taxBase];`  1) sizeof taxBase, depending on the size of `int` will multiply by 16 or 32, not what you want.  2) this accesses way beyond the end of the array taxBase

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for the comments and suggestions. I've made mistakes. I've corrected my answer accordingly. BR.